# Web Worker for Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to hybrid application development in Cordova+Sencha.I have developed an app for iOS and it is working fine ,but when moved to Android most of the functionalities are not working because of the use of Web Workers.Is there any alternative for Webworker in Sencha touch or Cordova ,which helps to migrate the existing code without much change and will work on both iOS and Cordova .Please help

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can try '`DroidGap`' instead of '`webView`' .

For Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried this but it is showing a warning "DroidGap is deprecated"

Comment: which version of cordova you are using?